Flexible height sheet for SwiftUI
I'm working on a SwiftUI sheet that can resize itself based on the content's height. The sheet works well until I introduce multi-line text.
To handle the dynamic height, I added .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) to the SheetHeightModifier, which fixes the height issue. However, when I do this, I notice an odd animation behavior with the button. It jumps up when you tap it. Here's my code.
Why would the button exhibit this behavior with the fixedSize modifier?
struct SheetHeightModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var height: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .background(
            GeometryReader { reader -> Color in
                height = reader.size.height
                print(height)
                return Color.clear
            }
        )
    }
}

struct PresentationDetentModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .modifier(SheetHeightModifier(height: $height))
            .presentationDetents([.height(height)])
    }
}

extension View {
    func flexiblePresentationDetents(height: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PresentationDetentModifier(height: height))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    @State var sheetHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present Sheet") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            VStack {
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
            }
            .padding()
            .flexiblePresentationDetents(height: $sheetHeight)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


Looking at the logs, the height read by the geometry reader is initially more than 8000pt for a split second, then changes to about 200, which is correct.
Because of this large height, the view presenting the sheet shrinks a bit (similar to when you use the .large detent), then very quickly after that the height goes back down and so the view moves back to the initial position. This causes the views to jiggle a bit because they are being laid out again.
A simple way to work around this is to just filter out these nonsensical heights from the geometry reader. If you are sure that the content size will never exceed some value, then you can ignore heights above that value. For example, here I have used 2000
// I also changed this to use a preference value instead of
// directly assigning to 'height' in the GeometryReader
struct HeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat? { nil }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        if let next = nextValue() {
            value = next
        }
    }
}

struct SheetHeightModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var height: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .background {
                GeometryReader { reader in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: HeightKey.self, value: reader.size.height)
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(HeightKey.self) {
                // the max height is 2000 - assume everything above that is nonsensical
                guard let newHeight = $0, newHeight < 2000 else {
                    return
                }
                height = newHeight
            }
    }
}

Or you can use min to limit the height to a value that won't cause the presenting view to move:
.onPreferenceChange(HeightKey.self) {
    guard let newHeight = $0 else {
        return
    }
    height = min(newHeight, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.88)
}

Unfortunately, unlike in this post, you cannot use a .custom detent, because they cannot take any parameters. While they do have access to EnvironmentValues, they are of the environment of the presenting view, not the sheet.

The print statement reveals that the Text starts with a very large height. If you print the width too then you will see that the reason for the large height is because is starts with a very small width. This in turn may be because it is performing some kind of zoom animation as the sheet appears.
It helps if you apply a min width to the content inside SheetHeightModifier. The actual minimum width will depend on the screen size. However, the minimum width may be less than the width of the screen, because a sheet on a large iPad does not occupy the full screen width.
It works quite well to use the width of an iPod (= 320) as the minimum width. This width is also less than the smallest iPad in one-third split-screen mode, so it should be pretty safe:
// SheetHeightModifier

content
    .frame(minWidth: 320) //  HERE
    // other modifiers as before

The highest iOS version for an iPod is iOS 15, so if you only support iOS 16 and above then you could even make the minimum width larger, say 340.
